# Django OSQA + PyBBM

Tags: django, package, admin, django-urls, osqa

here is my problem:
I have integrated PyBBM in OSQA and all the links in the admin section of the package are 'broken'

[image]

so for example when I click "add", the URL from

```
http://localhost:8080/osqa/nimda/
```

became

```
http://localhost:8080/osqa/nimda/(.*)pybb/category/add/
```

without changing page.

This is the main urls.py file of my project

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'', include('forum.urls')),
    (r'^groups/', include('pybb.urls', namespace='pybb')), # PYBBM
)

if 'rosetta' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns

handler404 = 'forum.views.meta.page'
handler500 = 'forum.views.meta.error_handler'
```

This is a part of the urls.py of 'forum', an app of OSQA

```
import startup

import os.path
from forum import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings as djsettings
from django.contrib import admin
from forum import views as app
from forum.sitemap import OsqaSitemap
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import logging

admin.autodiscover()

sitemaps = {
    'questions': OsqaSitemap
}

APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

try:
    admin_url = url(r'^%s(.*)' % _('nimda/'), admin.site.root)
except AttributeError:
    admin_url = url(r'^%s(.*)' % _('nimda/'), admin.site.urls)

# Choose the user urls pattern
if bool(settings.INCLUDE_ID_IN_USER_URLS.value):
    core_user_urls_prefix = r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)'
else:
    core_user_urls_prefix = r'^%s(?P<slug>.*)'

core_urls = (
    url(r'^$', app.readers.index, name='index'), admin_url,

[...]

    url(r'^%s$' % _('admin/'), app.admin.dashboard, name='admin_index'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('switch_interface/')), app.admin.interface_switch, name='admin_switch_interface'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('statistics/')), app.admin.statistics, name='admin_statistics'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('denormalize/')), app.admin.recalculate_denormalized, name='admin_denormalize'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('go_bootstrap/')), app.admin.go_bootstrap, name='admin_go_bootstrap'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('go_defaults/')), app.admin.go_defaults, name='admin_go_defaults'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<set_name>\w+)/(?P<var_name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('settings/')), app.admin.get_default, name='admin_default'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('maintenance/')), app.admin.maintenance, name='admin_maintenance'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('flagged_posts/')), app.admin.flagged_posts, name='admin_flagged_posts'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/')), app.admin.static_pages, name='admin_static_pages'),

    url(r'^%s%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/'), _('new/')), app.admin.edit_page, name='admin_new_page'),
    url(r'^%s%s%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/'), _('edit/')), app.admin.edit_page, name='admin_edit_page'),
    url(r'^%s%s%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/'), _('delete/')), app.admin.delete_page, name='admin_delete_page'),

    url(r'^%s%s(?P<name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('tools/')), app.admin.tools_page, name='admin_tools'),

    url(r'^%s%s(?P<set_name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('settings/')), app.admin.settings_set, name='admin_set'),

    url(r'%s%s' % (_('admin/'), _('test_email_settings/')), app.admin.test_email_settings, name='test_email_settings'),
```

As you can see there are two admin section, reachable with two different URL.

1) For the main admin page of OSQA: `http://localhost:8080/osqa/admin/`

[image]

2) For the admin page of the package PyBBM (at the start of the post) `http://localhost:8080/osqa/nimda/`

What could be the problem for the broken links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the admin url for Pybmm solved the problem

```
try:
    admin_url = url(r'^adminbb/', include(admin.site.root))#url(r'^%s(.*)' % _('nimda/'), admin.site.root)
except AttributeError:
    admin_url = url(r'^adminbb/', include(admin.site.urls))#url(r'^%s(.*)' % _('nimda/'), admin.site.urls)
```